# Design Time Data for DataGrid + DomainDataSource

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services, expression-blend, silverlight-5.0

I have setup a DataGrid to use a DomainDataSource and a DataPager. This post has a similar setup:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/subhendude/datagrid-paging-in-silverlight-using-wcf-ria-services/

Now, I need to do a lot of customization to a lot of columns. How do I setup design time data so this task will be easier in Blend? I have created sample data based on the same object type as the domain data source, but I don't know if I point the DomainDataSource to the sample data or point the datagrid to it.

Comment: did you managed to solve this ?